# How should I link businesses, areas and area managers knowing only their locations

Tags: database, database-design

I am developing an application and currently I am trying to figure out how I should set up my database tables and relationships and what exact data needs to go into which table. 
I need to be able to create and manage the following entities:

- Users (managers): They will be assigned to one **particular area** to manage (e.g. a town or a town subdivision). They will be able to enter in the name of the area they will manage and will have to select one of the suggestions that will be pulled from a google maps search.
- Businesses: These are individual businesses with one address. However, a business can be created with any address in the UK, **even if no manager has been assigned to manage the area where that business is located**.

Note that even if some businesses are created in an unmanaged area, once a manager is created for that area, he will automatically see all those businesses as his. This means that we can't assign a manager to each business individually as sometimes a manager might not exist for that area at the time of creation, but might be added in later on.

I have considered the following possible solution:

- Having 3 tables: Users, Areas and Businesses. Users would have a one-to-many relationship with Areas table, which would actually allow one user to manage several areas. Areas would have a one-to-many relationship with Businesses so that one Area could have multiple businesses. Each Business would have to be assigned to an area when created.
- This would work, but there is one problem with this: I would somehow have to create an Areas table with all possible areas in UK which would be a hard task. Not only would I have to add all areas, but I would also have to find and assign geo codes for each to do business  search within a certain radius around a post code later on. I do have a full UK postcode database file with over 2 million postcodes each having town, council, parish, ward, geo codes and some other info, however, each town subdivision (usually an electoral ward) has hundreds of postcodes and geo locations, which would make it very hard to try to generate an 'areas' table with only one central geo code or post code for each 'area' or town subdivision or whatever it is called.

So having explained my problem, I am asking you if my considered solution of having three tables, Users, Areas and Businesses, is actually a good solution, or if I have other better ways to solve this problem? Is there a better way in which I could approach this problem?

Any tips, info or answers would help a lot.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Should a manager be allowed to manage an area that has no businesses associated with it?

Comment: Can a user's area be bigger than a business's area? For example, can a business's area be a town's subdivision, while a user's area is the whole town?

Comment: Yes, a manager can be assigned an area regardless if it has businesses or not.
A manager can manager either a city, a town or a subdivision of a town, while a business can only have an address - a single point geo location. All businesses with addresses that fall within an area would be seen by the manager of the area as his (if a manager exists for that area). Geo coordinates would be generated for each area and  business.